# flutter: calculate widget size inside CustomSingleChildLayout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to use `CustomSingleChildLayout` like this:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: widget.route.animation,
      builder: (context, child) {
        final double bottomPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;

        return CustomSingleChildLayout(
          delegate: _BottomPickerLayout(widget.route.animation.value,
              bottomPadding: bottomPadding),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
              ),
            ),
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            elevation: 1.0,
            child: AltMonth(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

This is my deligate class :

```
class _BottomPickerLayout extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
  final double progress;
  final double bottomPadding;

  _BottomPickerLayout(
    this.progress, {
    this.bottomPadding = 0,
  });

  @override
  Size getSize(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return super.getSize(constraints);
  }

  @override
  BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {

    return BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
      maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
      minHeight: 0.0,
      maxHeight: 310 + bottomPadding,
    );
  }

  @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
    final height = size.height - childSize.height * progress;
    return Offset(0.0, height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant _BottomPickerLayout oldDelegate) {
    return progress != oldDelegate.progress;
  }
}
```

I want to calculate `AltMonth` widget size and replace it's size with `maxHeight: 310 + bottomPadding,`.  AltMonth widget has different size and I got error. How could I calculate `AltMonth widget` size ?

Comment: If you are going to replace it's size anyway, is there any need to calculate it first ?

Comment: I need to calculate it's size because I shows this widget @NisanthReddy

Comment: *"How could I calculate AltMonth widget size ?"* - all you can do is to get its `RenderBox` size, but actually it smells like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - what actually do you want to achieve with that `CustomSingleChildLayout`?

Comment: RenderBox is not accessible inside `SingleChildLayoutDelegate` because I don't have a context itself , If you pass context from it's parents how you can calculate `AltMonth`? I use `CustomSingleChildLayout` to achieve `AltMonth` open like bottomSheet (animation and overlay) . @pskink

Comment: so if you want to animate things, first of all remove `AnimatedBuilder` - instead use `Listenable? relayout` parameter  used in the delegate ctor, and for a size pass `AltMonth`'s `GloblaKey` so you can get `GlobalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject` - but still i am not sure you need that size

Comment: this is my result https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H14LYEP9CuK5ovwKzEdOCYRHCqvFS9XA/view?usp=sharing . Some thime height of `AltMonth` is more and for that I want to `getConstraintsForChild` automatically be changed with it's child. @pskink

Comment: Then in in your example how do you calculate `builder` size?@pskink

Comment: you dont have to, it fills completely `SliderBuilder` area (i used it some time ago so i may be wrong though...) - just try it and see how it works

Comment: Yes, In `AltMonth` widget I used Column so I added `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` and `SliderBuilder` be fitted . @pskink

Comment: I wondered that how `SliderBuilder` can calculate my widget size? @pskink

Comment: I found a problem? When I clicked on `SliderBuilder` , it is gone and I can't select anything on my widget? on my widget I have a button and I want to when I tapped on my button , the `SliderBuilder` be pop @pskink

Comment: ohh it was an old version: this one will work better: https://gist.github.com/pskink/2ac0787505bace2a2ebba06f133e642a - its a complete working demo with `main` so you can run it and see how it works

Comment: It's work but in devices with different sizes, this is cause problem https://pasteboard.co/K2gszkG.png and this is my code https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ZWDGJhrywY/ @pskink

Comment: remove `FractionallySizedBox` then - i used it only to make sure that both slide panels fill the screen completely

Comment: Thanks so much, It's work and done :-)

Comment: so it was much easier than fighting with child sizes, render boxes and custom layouts ;-) ...

Comment: Yes , It was so easier but How `SliderBuilder` calculate child size? Do'es it calculate or just let to lie down and doesn't matter what is the it's child size?@pskink

Comment: doesn't matter what is the it's child size, it is a work for `Align` widget